# Extract text from XML using C#

Tags: c#, xml, parsing, text

I work with XML documents that look like this:

[image]

All I need is extract the text between the tags. Since it's being successfully highlighted in black by a common XML editor, I'm assuming I should be able to extract it manually?

So far I've tried the following:

```
private void Form1_Load(System.Object sender, System.EventArgs e)
{
    XmlDocument doc = new XmlDocument();
    doc.Load("C:\\users\\admin\\desktop\\index.xml");

    foreach (object node_loopVariable in doc.ChildNodes) {
        node = node_loopVariable;
        ProcNode(node);
    }
}

private void ProcNode(XmlNode node)
{
    Console.WriteLine(node.InnerText);

    foreach (XmlNode subNode in node.ChildNodes) {
        Console.WriteLine(subNode.InnerText);
    }
}
```

Is that a reliable solution?

Comment: An actual XML snippet (as opposed to a screenshot of XML) would be helpful.  What code have you written so far?  Have you tried Linq to XML?  An XmlReader?  An XmlDocument?  What's working/not working?

Comment: May I suggest you break the portion of the XML document you are actually interested into a format that's easier on the eyes? Also what have you tried so far for XML parsing. Which type of parser are you interested in using?

Comment: Why don't you use Tools like DOM or SAX ?

Comment: it's easier if you show your attempt to extract the text and describe where that failed.

Answer (score 1):

Use the [`XDocument`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.xml.linq.xdocument.aspx) class to read the XML and query it using [LINQ to XML](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb387098.aspx).

Answer (score 0):

You can do something like that:

```
XmlDocument xmlDoc = new XmlDocument();
xmlDoc.Load(HttpContext.Current.Server.MapPath("App_Data/file.xml"));
XmlElement xelNo = xmlDoc.GetElementById("ElementID");
```

Then you can access the Attributes or Text of this Element;
But to use this you must know the ID of your element.